# How to handle event Double click using DataBinding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have project that I want to display a shape in `ShapeDesigner.xaml` to `Grid` in `MainWindow.xaml` when I double-click `ShapeToolUI.xaml` button, how can I do this. Thank you so much.
This is .xaml code

**ShapeDesigner.xaml**

```
<Canvas x:Name="Canvas">
    <!-- Draw circle-->
    <ContentControl x:Name="Circle"
        Width="366" Height="312" Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="50"
        MinWidth="50" MaxWidth="200" MinHeight="50" MaxHeight="200"
                Template="{StaticResource DesignShape}" RenderTransformOrigin="3.005,2.555">
        <Ellipse Fill="Red"
                 IsHitTestVisible="False"></Ellipse>
        
    </ContentControl>
</Canvas>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid Background="#FFBCE6FF" >
    // I want to display Canvas in ShapeDesigner in here when double-clicked button in ShapeToolUI
</Grid>
```

**ShapeToolUI.xaml**

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
        <StackPanel Background="#FFBCE6FF">
            <Button  MouseDoubleClick="DisplayRhombus"
                Margin="10,40,10,0" Height="91" Width="100" BorderBrush="#FFBCE6FF" Foreground="#FFBCE6FF">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="rhombus.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
</Grid>
```

Thank you so much <3

Comment: Why is there a button there with no command or event handler? Buttons are designed to do stuff when you click them.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your "DisplayRhombus" defined?
If not, that need to be defined first. And invoke "Circle" from inside that function.